Sleep system call very broken on MacOSX
I'm trying to run a service on my Mac Mini M1. But it has unexplained random delays from few seconds to 20 minutes many times during the day. It works perfectly on linux.
Sleep appears to be very broken on MacOSX. The machine doesn't run anything else, only a few development tools are installed, screen and keyboard are not connected. I made a minimal reproduction:
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>


int main()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Wall clock: " << now << std::endl;
    }
}

Example of 15 minute sleep instead of 10 seconds (this happens many times):
Wall clock: 2024-07-02 05:34:08.577015
Wall clock: 2024-07-02 05:34:18.705682
Wall clock: 2024-07-02 05:34:28.853954
Wall clock: 2024-07-02 05:50:42.539091
Wall clock: 2024-07-02 05:50:52.582264

% cat localhost.sleep_test.plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>localhost.sleep_test</string>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/sleep_test.sh</string>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/Users/user/sleep_test-output.txt</string>
        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/Users/user/sleep_test-errors.txt</string>
    </dict>
</plist>

% launchctl load localhost.sleep_test.plist
% launchctl start localhost.sleep_test

% uname -a
Darwin MacMini 23.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.5.0: Wed May  1 20:16:51 PDT 2024; root:xnu-10063.121.3~5/RELEASE_ARM64_T8103 arm64

% clang --version
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin


Have you checked the error output for that time? What about system logs for that time? Do you have the same problem if you run the program as a normal program and not as a daemon through launchctl?

Does the computer have low-power/hibernate/suspend timers?  If so does the code need to responded to system events to avoid being "put-to-sleep"?

If you want to prevent the system from going to sleep so you can do your important work every 10 seconds there's code for that. But then you might as well just disable sleeping at the OS level. And of course enjoy the power bill.

Indeed, it does look like the Mac goes to sleep. There is nothing in the system logs for that time interval. I'm struggling to run my service using websocket, it also has 20 minute delays and it just continues like nothing happened. This small C++ program is just to demonstrate the issue.

Settings -> Display -> Advanced -> “Prevent automatic sleep on power adapter when the screen turns off”

App Nap?
